# Safari (in-app) browser breaking website rendering

Tags: ios, facebook, browser, safari, in-app

I have some issues with the browser safari(in-app).
I have a website http://www.instylebuzz.com working perfectly.
Somehow I see very different versions of my website when I open it within in-app browser (specifically FB)

When I say different versions, it means depending on the browser version (or maybe the app version), the website style is looking different.
It is right I have a lot of differences between my mobile, tablet, and desktop version, but nevertheless, I should not see broken style,
because the three of them are styled ok.

So, my questions is simple, how can I effectively target in-app browser, knowing the user agent can change per app version/browser/os version?
How can I fix my website rendering on in-app Browser.

I'm searching days and nights for this solution,
it would be very kind if someone know/can help with my problem.

Thanks,

Simon

***PS: for purposes, you should check a post rendering on the website, not a category or homepage.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this has been some time since this thread.
But if someone encounters the problem, here is the solution.

Because the safari (in-app) and Safari classic on iOS have different default browser styles, if you see some css issues, it is because each browser interpret your css in a different way, and sometimes it might not be the result you expected.

Therefore, you can use:
Meyer Reset CSS, but you will probably have some work to do on your CSS to make everything good again. https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

User normalize.css https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/